# Missing GetPentagram class on use

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I was following the instruction of PDFSharp in their site. Now there's a sample that uses GetPentagram which will draw a polygon. But there are no suggestion for the said class to be imported. Below is the sample code

```
void DrawPolygon(XGraphics gfx, int number)
{
  BeginBox(gfx, number, "DrawPolygon");

  XPen pen = new XPen(XColors.DarkBlue, 2.5);

  gfx.DrawPolygon(pen, XBrushes.LightCoral, GetPentagram(50, new XPoint(60, 70)), XFillMode.Winding);
  gfx.DrawPolygon(pen, XBrushes.LightCoral, GetPentagram(50, new XPoint(180, 70)), XFillMode.Alternate);

  EndBox(gfx);
}
```

Now it can't find the GetPentagram class so I don't know where/what package to import that contains this class. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetPentagram` is part of the sample. It does not work if you just copy a single method without the referenced methods.

https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-samples/blob/master/samples/core/Graphics/Base.cs

Comment: Thanks for this... Didn't know there's a repo example to this I was just using the code in http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_simple_lines_0 and this didn't have the function and class needed. Thanks really helped me